# Get the list of all the files with ".txt" after changing the current working directory

Tags: python

I changed the current working directory and then I want to list all the files in that directory with extension `.txt`. How can I achieve this?

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import os

path = "/home/pawn/Desktop/projects_files"
os.chdir(path)

## checking working directory
print ("working directory "+ os.getcwd()+'\n')
```

Now how to list all the files in the current directory (**projects_files**) with extension `.txt`?

Comment: see python's [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/glob.html) module

Answer (score 2):

Use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/glob.html#glob.iglob), which is a wildcard search for files, and you don't need to change the directory either:

```
import glob

for f in glob.iglob('/home/pawn/Desktop/project_files/*.txt'):
   print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob. With glob you can use wildcards as you would do in your system command line. For example:

> ```
> import glob
> print( glob.glob('*.txt') )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `glob` in python.

It will help you to fetch the files of a particular format..

## Usage

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/glob.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to `import glob` as suggested in the other good answers here, you can also do it with the same `os` moudle:

```
path = "/home/pawn/Desktop/projects_files"    
[f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt')]
```